# Web Interface to CVS repository

Tags: unix, repository, cvs

Does anybody know of a Web Interface for CVS repositories.

I work on Ubuntu 10.04

**UPDATE:** I have found by lots of Options by [Googling](http://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=cvs+interface+browser), but wanted to know which one(s) people use here. Will give me a heads up instead of me getting to know each & every Interface out there...

Comment: If you want to poll on which web interface is most widely used, perhaps one tool per answer and Community Wiki may be appropriate...

Comment: i am unable to make my question a community wiki

Comment: *i am unable to make my question a community wiki* – you should be able these days, I guess :) Although this sounds off-topic these days

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ViewVC](http://www.viewvc.org/) is the interface used by SourceForge.  I found a ton of other interfaces just by Googling "web CVS interface."

Comment: I too have found by googling, but wanted to know which one(s) people use here. Will give me a heads up instead of me getting to know each & every Interface out there...

Comment: You might revise your question then.  As it stands, the answer "yes" would be valid.  Make your question more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Within ubuntu's Apt repository, there are packages for:
 * [viewvc](http://www.viewvc.org/)
 * [csvweb](http://www.freebsd.org/projects/cvsweb.html)

Both which can be installed by typing, eg `apt-get install viewvc`

Answer (score 0):

I use [`cvsweb`](http://www.freebsd.org/projects/cvsweb.html) on Solaris, but it's easily `apt-get install`ed on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

cvstrac: http://cvstrac.org/
is the one that i used in several projects